# Plumbing Toilet Jet Rims, One Hole bigger than others?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, repair, toilet

I am trying to check if my toilet jet rims are working properly or chipped.

Is one jet hole supposed to be bigger than the others? Its releasing more water, when flushing toilet. The bigger hole is at front right, when facing toilet.

Wondering when I used very small Allen wrench to clean with CLR, did I chip away at a hole (I was being careful), or built by design?

If an issue, anyway to fix bigger hole, or just get new toilet? This is old toilet from 1980s, 1990s. In taking a mirror, and checking underneath, it looks somewhat bigger, but does not seemed chipped at all. Might be a manufacturing thing, not sure.

**Resource:** https://www.thespruce.com/cleaning-toilet-jets-2719011

Comment: A picture would be helpful.  Make sure you don't drop your camera/phone.

Comment: well its just a question of if one jet hole should be bigger than another, a picture prob wont help, kind of dark underside of toilet, and looks like a regular toilet, I could post a stock photo, and no one could tell thanks cc @SteveWellens

Comment: what problem is it causing?

Comment: no problems for now, @jsotola just curious if something to look out of, or why one hole is bigger, manufacturing defect, thanks

Comment: On mine I think the three front holes are larger.  Maybe other of your other front holes are plugged? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a uniform ring of holes around the top rim, all facing downward, it is normal to have *slight* variations in size, but not so much that you would notice unless you were inspecting closely.

If one hole on one side is intentionally pointed diagonally or horizontally, that's to wash the bowl and create a vortex, and that might be intentionally bigger.

In a white toilet if the holes are clogged with white calcification they might become very uneven.

In an older toilet (1980s is old enough) there can be significant calcium deposits inside the channels leading from the tank to the holes.  This can reduce flow so much that the bowl gets cleaned unevenly or the toilet doesn't flush well.   Supposedly you can fix this by filling the tank with vinegar or CLR and flushing it through but that doesn't work.  Supposedly you can tape up all the holes so the channels get soaked in the solution for a while.  I've never had success with this.  When a toilet gets this bad, I've always ended up replacing it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not unusual for the holes under the rim to be non uniform.
You said it is not causing a problem.
If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Does the hole *look* like it's chipped, or does the glazing smoothly cover it?

If it *looks* chipped, then it's most likely chipped. If it looks factory original, then it probably is.

Comment: The glaze (made of glass) would be missing on a chip, you can't actually see any porcelain from the outside under normal circumstances. A fingernail scratch test can quickly discriminate between the two; porcelin feels like an emery board, glaze feels like a beer bottle.

Comment: Fair point, @dandavis. I picked the wrong terms, my apologies.